# Loading Scripts and Breaking on Error

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I've written the following to let me load scripts from an array:

```
scriptLoader = (function(){

  var loader = function (src, handler) {
    if(!self.errorstate){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            script.onerror = loaderror(src);
            script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = null;
        };
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        (head || document.body).appendChild(script);
    }
  };

  var loaderror = function (src) {
    self.errorstate = true;
    console.log('Error: '+src);
    return false;
  };

  var self = {};
  self.errorstate = false;
  self.files = null;
  self.callback = null;
  self.go = function(){
    if (self.files.length !== 0) {
        loader(self.files.shift(), arguments.callee);
    } else {
        if (self.callback && typeof (self.callback) === 'function' && !self.errorstate) {
            self.callback();
        }
    }
  };
  return self;

});
```

Which I'm calling with:

```
var scripts = [
    'js/placeholder.js',
    'js/modal.js',
    'js/alert.js',
    'js/notafile.js'
];


loader = new scriptLoader();
loader.files = scripts;
loader.callback = alert('loaded');
loader.go();
```

Everything seems to work except I can't get it to break on error (`js/notafile.js`) - so stop loading any more scripts and not allow the callback to fire. It shows the error message in the console fine, I just can't find a good way to stop it!

Comment: `loader.callback = alert('loaded');` This code doesn't do what you think it does `:P`

Comment: Have you declared `errorstate`, and `self` somewhere? Implied global properties are a bad practice.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - what does it do?

Comment: Well, haven't you noticed? The alert is called immediately, and its return value (which is `undefined`) is assigned to the "callback" property of the loader. You have to define the callback as a function expression: `loader.callback = function () { alert(...); };`.

Comment: So, is there a good solution to fix it?

Comment: I would need to know if `self` is declared somewhere... (especially since there already exists a global property with that name, which refers to the global object itself)

Comment: What you see is what's there, I'm at the very begginning of this, so there's no other code.

Comment: Should I change self to something particular to that class?

Comment: No, just declare it as a local variable: `var self = {};` instead of `self = {};`

Comment: Ok, so I've done that, how do I work out the callback firing issue?

Comment: Inside the "loader" function, you're not using the `handler` parameter anywhere. From what I can see, only the first script is loaded. Also, the "readystatechange" event fires multiple times during the script load, and you're `null`-ifying both it, and the "load" handler on the fist occurrence of "readystatechange", so the "load" event is not handled. Also, you don't need the `new` - "scriptLoader" is not an constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try / catch + throw

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

```
var loaderror = function (src) {
    errorstate = true;
    throw 'Error: '+src;
    return false;
};
```

and

```
var scripts = [
    'js/placeholder.js',
    'js/modal.js',
    'js/alert.js',
    'js/notafile.js'
];


loader = new scriptLoader();
loader.files = scripts;
loader.callback = alert('loaded');

try{
   loader.go();
}catch(err){
   console.log(err);
}
```